# how to ignore index.php file from urlrewrite

Tags: .htaccess

This is my simple htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule    ^books/([A-Za-z0-9.]+)$    library/search.php?zig=$1    [NC,L]
```

My code is working fine for the followings:

```
mydomain/books/math
mydomain/books/english
mydomain/books/physics.applied
```

as

```
library/search.php?zig=math
library/search.php?zig=english
library/search.php?zig=physics.applied
```

But my code is not working only for

```
mydomain/books/
```

it is acting as

```
library/search.php?zig=index.php
```

There is no subject named index.php. I want to remove this index.php. My search function should not work for  **mydomain/books/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `RewriteCond` to ignore all files and directories from rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^books/([A-Za-z0-9.]+)$ library/search.php?zig=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```